# Explicit inverse of $\lambda-U$ when $U$ is unitary and $|\lambda|<1$

Tags: operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, spectral-theory

Let $U$ be a unitary operator on a Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$. By the spectral theorem, it is known that $\sigma(U)\subseteq \{z\in \mathbb{C}:|z|=1\}$. How can the explicit inverse of $\lambda-U$ be calculated for $|\lambda|<1$ (or $|\lambda|>1$)?

Next let $R$ be the right shift operator on $l^{2}(\mathbb{N})$. Consider $[R]\in \frac{B(l^{2}(\mathbb{N}))}{K(l^{2}(\mathbb{N}))}$, where $K(l^{2}(\mathbb{N})$) is the set of compact operators on $l^{2}(\mathbb{N})$, and so the algebra considered is the Calkin algebra. $R$ is then unitary mod a compact operator, i.e., $[R]$ is unitary in the Calkin algebra. How can the explicit inverse of $\lambda-[R]$ be found for $|\lambda|<1$ (or $|\lambda>1$)?

Comment: I do not think that you can have an explicit formula for the resolvent of $R$ in the Calkin algebra. The problem is that you cannot write explicitely the Hilbert space, where the Calkin algebra acts. On the other hand, you can consider the image of $R$ in the Toeplitz algebra modulo compact operators. It can be realized explicitely as algebra of multiplication operators on the unit circle. Thereby $[R]$ is multiplication by $z$.

Comment: What have you tried? For the explicit formula, have a look at this [question and answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1627600/if-u-is-unitary-operator-then-spectrum-sigmau-is-contained-inside-the-uni) or this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2648107/spectrum-of-unitary-operators-lie-in-the-unit-circle).