# Spectrum of unitary operators lie in the unit circle

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, spectral-theory

$U$ - unitary operator on complex Hilbert space. Show that
$\sigma(U) \subset \{z \in\mathbb C : |z| = 1\}.$

So $U$ is unitary operator if is is surjective and it preserves a scalar product and a unitary operator is a bounded linear operator $U : H → H$ on a Hilbert space H that satisfies $U^*U = UU^* = I$, where $U^*$ is the adjoint of $U$, and $I : H \to H$ is the identity operator.

But how do I show that $\sigma(U) \subseteq \{z \in C : |z| = 1\}.$ ?

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: If you know the spectral mapping theorem, then consider the map $f$ sending $z \mapsto z^* z$. We immediately get $f(\sigma(U)) = \sigma(f(U)) = \sigma(I) = \{1\}$ as desired.

Comment: Why is no answer accepted?

Comment: @ViktorGlombik The spectral mapping theorem can be extended to all normal operators in $T \in L(X)$ and $f \in \mathcal{C}(\sigma(T))$.

Answer (score 15):

A unitary operator $U$ is invertible with inverse $U^{-1}=U^*$. So
$\|U\|=\|U^{-1}\|=1$. Any operator $B$ with $\|B\| < 1$ is such that $I-B$ is invertible with $(I-B)^{-1}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}B^{n}$. Therefore, if $|\lambda| < 1$, the following is invertible:
$$
     U-\lambda I = U(I-\lambda U^{-1})
$$
And, for $|\lambda| > 1$, the following is also invertible:
$$
       U-\lambda I=-\lambda\left(I-\frac{1}{\lambda}U\right)
$$
So the spectrum of a unitary $U$ is a subset of the unit circle in the complex plane.

Answer (score 8):

Here's a few useful observations that should help you, and that should be proven if you're not familiar with them.  All of them have easy proofs.

For an operator $T\in\mathcal B(H)$, we have the following

- $\sigma(T^*)=\{\overline{\lambda}:\lambda\in\sigma(T)\}$
- If $T$ is invertible, then $\sigma(T^{-1})=\{\lambda^{-1}:\lambda\in\sigma(T)\}$
- $\|T^*T\|=\|T\|^2$
- $\sup\{|\lambda|:\lambda\in\sigma(T)\}\leq\|T\|.$